How to measure correlation between anxiety level (score 20-80) and parenting style (authoritarian, authoritative, permissive)?
As the title says, I am wondering how to measure the correlation between anxiety level and parenting style, as one is ordinal and the other is categorical.
Is Spearman's correlation the right method? If not, what should I use?

When one variable is categorical  (and not ordinal) and has more than two categories, correlation isn't possible or useful If you tell us what you are trying to do, in ordinary language, maybe we can help.

What does correlation mean here? I suspect you want to look for differences in anxiety between the three groups.

Correlation is symmetric, but I would move straight on past it as previous comments are I think saying too. Yet what to do may entail a method that is asymmetric. Do you regard parenting style as outcome or predictor?

Do you consider the 3 levels of parenting style to be simply categorical without an order among them, or is there an ordering from "authoritarian" to "authoritative" to "permissive"? How did you estimate the parenting style itself? Might there have been some continuous measure that you have reduced to those categories? When you address what's been suggested in these comments, please do so by editing the original question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

I don't see authoritative as fitting in the middle. I could be authoritarian or permissive to children or to students or to junior colleagues. Authoritative is an adjective I might use about what someone has written to be read or used, but hardly otherwise.

"Authoritative" is used in parenthood literature to refer to a parenting style that is (roughly) strict but warm. I don't know how they decided on the term, it's very confusing as the other major style is the "Authoritarian" which means strict and cold/harsh. So very different styles but almost the same word.
